# Is there any way to mock a class using a class variable?

Tags: java, jmockit

I would like to mock a list of classes. So far, I have something like:

```
List<Class<? extends ParentClass>> classes =  
    new ArrayList<Class<? extends ParentClass>>(Arrays.asList(ClassA.class,ClassB.class,ClassC.class));
for (Class<? extends ParentClass> childClass : classes) {
    mockAllChildClasses();
    new MockUp<childClass>() {
        @Mock
        public String process() {
            // return some string specific to this class
        }
    };
    // verify that the tested method returns the class-specific string mocked above;
}
```

But since I can't simply put the childClass variable inside <>, I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Maybe there are alternatives to using Mockup<> or there is some way to put a variable between <>.

(Apologies for the vague title. Not quite sure how to word it.)

Comment: _Why_ do you want to "mock" the classes? How are you trying to use this? Would passing `List<Supplier<? extends ParentClass>>` do what you need?

Comment: Your motivation for this question may have relevance since this question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Fair question. I essentially have a list of processors (classes) in which their respective process() method gets called. If any process method returns a non-null value, my method should return that non-null value. I am trying to ensure that my method returns that non-null value if any of those processors return a non-null value.

And I want to ensure that the logic checks out for all of them.

(In my example, I would return something like childClass.getExemption() instead of null. I had put null for simplicity. I'll change the post to reflect that.)

Comment: I have not used this Supplier class, but thanks for the tip. I'll look into it.